# Is it possible to set height and width of image which was assigned to a label dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i am using the code below to append image to a `label` text

`lblPopUp.Text = "<img src='Popup(Images)/notfound.png' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Access Denied,Contact Administrator";`

This results me as follow when loaded

[image]

Is it possible to change some what as below so that text and image should look similar

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little string manipulation should accomplish what you want, if I understand you correctly.

Code:

```
lblPopup.Text = "<img src='Popup(Images)/notfound.png' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Access Denied,Contact Administrator";
String strInsertStyle = " style=\"height: 100px; width: 100px;\"";
int intInsertPoint = lblPopup.Text.IndexOf("<img") + 4;
lblPopup.Text = lblPopup.Text.Substring(0, intInsertPoint) + strInsertStyle + lblPopup.Text.Substring(intInsertPoint);
```

Edit:
I am also assuming you mean you want to add the height/width later, otherwise go with jadarnel27's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height and width with the `height` and `width` attributes of the `<img>` tag:

```
lblPopUp.Text = "<img src='Popup(Images)/notfound.png' height='50px' width='50px' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Access Denied,Contact Administrator";
```

Alternately, you could use the `style` attribute:

```
lblPopUp.Text = "<img src='Popup(Images)/notfound.png' style='height:50px; width:50px;' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Access Denied,Contact Administrator";
```

---

One more thing: I would *strongly* reccomend against using all those `&nbsp`s to get your alignment right.  Putting some `padding-right` on your `<img>` tag will be much easier and much more stable.

Comment: Apologies in advance for the absence of jQuery ;-)